# Java Generic Insertion Sort and Selection sort in Arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I'm trying to implement insertion sort and it works for one weird implementation but in reverse order. The same goes for another selection sort I was trying but it working the same way.

```
void insertionSort(ArrayList<T> genericAList) {
        for (int n = 1; n < genericAList.size(); n++) {// go from start to end
            // n=genericList.size
            //n is primary index, j is secondary ind
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // This sorts in descending order
//WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK?? for (int j = n-1; j>0; j--) {
                if (genericAList.get(n).compareTo(genericAList.get(j)) == 1) {
                    T ncopy = genericAList.get(n);
                    genericAList.set(n, genericAList.get(j));
                    genericAList.set(j, ncopy);
                }
            }

//unsuccessfully trying to copy the array to reverse the order
                ArrayList<T> copy = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = genericAList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // start from end of old
                    copy.add(genericAList.get(i));
                }
    //            genericAList=copy;
            }
    //        return clone();
        }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing now? Where is your generic type `T` declaration and how does it look like?

Comment: It just compares a personobj.age attribute and the code works fine currently but it sorts in descending order. I was trying to get the commented out for loop to work.

Comment: The generic type declaration is related the type parameter for the objects and the arraylist' type parameter in my code

Answer (score 0):

Note that compareTo is not guaranteed to return -1 or 1 for larger or smaller.

It returns 0 if they are the same, and then a number larger or smaller than 0 if they are different.

Imagine the pseudo-code for a primitive form of this - if we're comparing two numbers for instance we might do this:

```
 public int compareTwoNumbers(x, y) {
     return x - y;
 }
```

So comparing 5 and 3 will give you -2 or 2 (for instance, depending on which way around they are).

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should be `int j = n; j > 0; j--`, the `== 1` should be `> 0`, and you're comparing/swapping the element at `n` when it should be `j - 1`.